# tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits for binary classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a model where I have to classify my data into two classes. Most of the codes use `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` for calculating cross entropy for binary classification.

When I use the same function to I train my model, I am getting negative values of entropy. I want to ask if I can use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to overcome the negative entropy?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, Pixels])
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([Pixels, Nodes1], stddev=0.01))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([Nodes1]))
y1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([Nodes1, Labels], stddev=0.01))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([Labels]))
y = tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2
cross_entropy = 
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, 
logits=y_))
```

Comment: I suppose you have accidentally switched labels and logits for the cross entropy call. The output of your model should be the logits. Maybe you could post all of your code.

Comment: so if i replace can I overcome negative entropy while training. beside can I use tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits for binary classification

Comment: As always, it depends. If your classes are mutually exclusive, then use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. If not, stick with it.

Comment: can I use tf.nn.relu function as an activation function and tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits for calculating cross entropy

Comment: You're free to use any activation function in your model, but remember to feed the raw logits to `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`.